# ASP.NET User Messaging / Chat - Off the shelf solution?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

We have an ASP.NET MVC solution and we'd like to integrate collaborative features like user to user messaging, group messaging and instant messaging.

I can't help but feel we are about to re-invent a wheel which as been re-invented time and time again.

Does anyone have some recommendations for off the shelf solutions we can integrate? Commercial or Open Source both welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an open source chat client have a look at [Jabbr](https://github.com/JabbR/JabbR)

> JabbR is a chat application built with ASP.NET using SignalR.

Answer (score 1):

Don't think that for simple solution you need some 3rd part library or SDK. You can for sure relay on  [SignalR](http://signalr.net/) library delivered fro `ASP.NET MVC` too.

That library wraps different communication technologies, and let you to write and handle push-like notification services. The best example on those ones is actually `Chat` application.

The basic idea is at the moment user connects to your `ASP.NET MVC` server using [SignalR](http://signalr.net/) it creates persistent connection from the server to the browser. So when the message from one client arrives you can notify *other* connected clients end-point (browser in this case).

Hope this helps.

Comment: The OP would still be re-inventing the chat portion of it. I think the question is more, "Has someone already created a chat package based on X, Y or Z technologies" - where SignalR is X, Y or Z.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead: it's pretty trivial write basic chat application with SignalR that perfectly hides all complicated implementation details under the hood. Having that in your hands you can after, if you need that, enhance and customize as you like it, which would hardly possible, and often that true with 3rd part libraries. *It is* basically an SDK

Comment: The OP has specifically stated that they don't want to re-invent the wheel. You could just as easily say "Use the `System.Net` namespace, it has `Socket`, so it's basically an SDK". You've just provided another starting point rather than address the "re-invention of the wheel" part of the question.. which I think is the core of the question.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead: at some point you *has to start*. Is this is a wheel or something that going to be a wheel has very thin and often subjective shape. This is, imo, an optimal solution will you can do not wary about deep implementation details but still have complete flexibility and scalability in the future.

Answer (score 1):

It is not free, but you might want to check out [CuteChat](http://cutesoft.net/ASP.NET+Chat/).

> It runs entirely from the web browsers. A completely web-based interface, requiring only Javascript and HTML (no ActiveX, Java applets, or other downloads required).